# Can pysvn 1.6.3 be made to work with Subversion 1.6 under linux?

Tags: python, linux, svn, pysvn

I see no reference on their website for this. I get pysvn to configure and build, but then it fails all the test. Has anyone had any luck getting this to work under linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot.

Your best bet is to use Subversion 1.5.5. See [the site](http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_status.html) for more details.

Comment: Try it. 

It'll probably work for the most part, but there will probably be things that randomly break. The API has changed in between the 1.5.x and 1.6.x series.

Comment: I am not sure how it built if the API has changed. Wouldn't it complain when the header files mis-match what it expects?

Comment: What I'm saying is you can try to build it, and if it works, great. 

But it wasn't tested to do so by upstream, so odd behaviour is to be expected.